# Prepare for Segue with iOs 10.0

Tags: swift, segue, ios10

Adding the code

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
```

has resulted in the error: **overriding 'prepare' must be as available as declaration it overrides** when trying to implement:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

Is this easily fixable?

Thanks.

Comment: No need to add `@available(iOS 10.0, *)` with `prepareForSegue` it will  work with old iOS too because it is not the new method, It's signature is changed in Swift 3 nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement following code..

```
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

          override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

               // if(segue.identifier == "segue"){

               //     let temp : UINavigationController =  segue.destination as! UINavigationController
               //     let second : ViewController =  temp.viewControllers.first as! ViewController       

               // }

         } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
         }
   }
```